# How to set up a React app on Apache server without modifying .htaccess file?

Tags: reactjs, apache, .htaccess, react-router

I am trying to deploy a React app on an Apache server where I do not have permissions to modify server configs. The server config sets AllowOverride to None, therefore, I can't use htaccess Rewrite Engine config.The deployed website does not render and React-router does not route pages.

Is there any other way to get a React app to work on an Apache server?

I tried searching for alternatives for react-router and server-side rendering options but still lost.

Thank you for any guidance!

Answer (score 0):

instead of messing with servers why not run your app on
https://www.netlify.com/. i would have added this as a comment but i don't have 50 rep points yet.

I've hosted 2 react apps on netlify. it works great and can run from github repos with minimal (almost zero) setup, and no messing with servers. great for front end guys like me.

Comment: It’s for a university project so, unfortunately, I have to stick to those servers.